# Edicion de un script Dinamico para actualizar informacion en MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un problema al recorrer el camino para que un usuario pueda editar información en un modelo y guardar esa nueva información en el modelo.

Empecemos, tengo este controlador que me ayuda a recuperar información de una base de datos y guardarla en un modelo.

```
 public PartialViewResult Detail(Int32 ID,String EmpNum)
    {
        ClinicHistoryModel model = new ClinicHistoryModel()
        {
            HistoriaClinica = Tabla1.Where(x => x.ID_HistoriaClinica == ID).First(),
            AntecedentesLaborales = tabla2.Any(x => x.ID_HistoriaClinica == ID) ?
                tabla2.Where(x => x.ID_HistoriaClinica == ID).ToList() 
                : new List<tabla2>(),
            ExamenClinico = tabla3.Where(x => x.ID_HistoriaClinica == ID).First(),
            ExploracionFisica = tabla4.Where(x => x.ID_HistoriaClinica == ID).First(),
            GinecoObstetricos = tabla5.Any(x => x.ID_HistoriaClinica == ID) ?
                tabla5.Where(x => x.ID_HistoriaClinica == ID).First()
                : new tabla5(),
            HeredoFamiliares = tabla6.Where(x => x.ID_HistoriaClinica == ID).First(),
            InterrogatorioSistemas = tabla7.Where(x => x.ID_HistoriaClinica == ID).First(),
            PersonalesNoPatologicos = tabla8.Where(x => x.ID_HistoriaClinica == ID).First(),
            PersonalesPatologicos = tabla9.Where(x => x.ID_HistoriaClinica == ID).First(),
        };
```

Una vez tengo el modelo lleno con la información del empleado al que estoy apuntando, se desencadena la acción de editar la información (si es el caso). Luego, este modelo se envía de nuevo a la vista para que se pueda manipular.

Una vez editado el modelo, este se recupera en el controlador y se envía a mi función 'SaveClinicHistory'. En dicha función, se recibe el modelo editado, se inicia una transacción y se guarda utilizando db.SaveChanges();. Al menos, esa es la idea para la edición, y funciona en otro módulo de la aplicación web.

```
private bool SaveChangeClinicHistory(ClinicHistoryModel model, bool isEditing){
using (DbContextTransaction dbTran = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        if (isEditing)
        {
            var editarHistoriaClinica = db.ClinicalHistories.Find(model.HistoriaClinica.ID_HistoriaClinica);
            var editarAntecedentesLaborales = db.WorkHistory
                .Where(x => x.ID_HistoriaClinica == model.HistoriaClinica.ID_HistoriaClinica).ToList();
            var editarHeredoFamiliares = db.FamilyHistory.Find(model.HeredoFamiliares.ID_HeredoFamiliares);
            var editarPersonalesPatologicos = db.MedicalHistory.Find(model.PersonalesPatologicos.ID_PersonalesPatologicos);
            var editarPersonalesNoPatologicos = db.NonMedicalHistory.Find(model.PersonalesNoPatologicos.ID_PersonalesNoPatologicos);
            var editarExploracionFisica = db.PhysicalExamination.Find(model.ExploracionFisica.ID_ExploracionFisica);
            var editarInterrogatoriosSistemas = db.SystemsInterrogation.Find(model.InterrogatorioSistemas.ID_InterrogatorioAparatosYSistemas);
            var editarExamenClinico = db.LaboratoryExaminations.Find(model.ExamenClinico.ID_ExamenesLaboratorio);

            
        

                    if (editarHistoriaClinica != null)
                    {

                        model.HistoriaClinica.ModifiedBy = Settings.EnviromentVars.LoggedUser.ID_User;
                        model.HistoriaClinica.LastModification = DateTime.Now;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }


        // Más código según sea necesario

        dbTran.Commit();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Manejar la excepción, hacer rollback si es necesario
        dbTran.Rollback();
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

En este caso solo editamos una tabla de ejemplo... Pero una vez damos click en el boton de 'Guardar', el siguiente script no me deja continuar,

```
$('#btnCreate').click(function () {
            debugger;
            var Signature = document.getElementById('HistoriaClinica_Signature').toDataURL().replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
            if (Signature == initial_HistoriaClinica_Signature) {
                alert('La firma digital es requerida');
            }
            else {
                fnCompleteFields();
                $('#HistoriaClinica_Signature').val(Signature);
                $('#Signature').val(Signature);
                //$('form').submit();

                var model = {
                    HistoriaClinica: {
                        ID_HistoriaClinica: 49,
                        EmpNum: '',
                        ID_TipoExamen: 0,
                        ModifiedBy:0,
                        Signature: $('#Signature').val()
    
                    }
                };
                
                ('/ClinicHistory/Post');
            }
        });
```

Me refiero a que no me deja continuar como es. Una vez construida la lógica, creé como test un JSON llamado "model" para probar valores aleatorios, pero no es funcional ya que no lo terminé. Incluso comencé a jugar con el debugger para ver el comportamiento del código. Hasta ahí todo iba bien, pero hice un *commit* **pero utilice Team Fundation (TFVC) que es el mismo gestor de versiones que viene con Visual Studio** y a partir de ahí, dicho script no me deja editarlo. Además, **el archivo que contiene el script solo se puede visualizar en tiempo de ejecución, por lo que, por alguna razón, no me permite editarlo.** También lo busqué en el directorio de mi solución y no encuentro nada. Mis primeras sospechas eran la operación de *commit* que realicé, pero el historial de cambios parece estar en orden. La verdad es que no tengo experiencia en el manejo de scripts dinámicos ni nada por el estilo. Cualquier ayuda será de provecho. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El archivo que se estaba tratando de editar era uno dinamico creado por las mismas librerias de jQuery, simplemente se busco entre el directorio de la solucion la funcion que se estaba tratando de editar :).